# Did the Fugitive Slave Act ever get repealed?

Tags: united-states, slavery

I know that slavery has been outlawed in the United States, but I was wondering if anyone got around to repealing the Fugitive Slave Act.

Comment: At the top of Wikipedia; in the info box, it clearly contains this information. Voting to close. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugitive_Slave_Act_of_1850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was repealed [June 28, 1864](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/statutes-at-large/38th-congress/session-1/c38s1ch166.pdf).